# crypto++ fails with string from a file?

Tags: c++, encryption, crypto++

I am using version 5.6.2 of the cryptopp library, and attempting to do some simple AES encryption of a string which I then send to a file and then attempt read again.

My calls all work fine when I encrypt and decrypt a string in the same function. But it's saving the thing to a file that is not working.

My unit test is like this:

```
TEST_METHOD(TestEncryptedFile)
{
    using namespace std;
    HardWareInfo info;
    std::ofstream outfile(_T("test.dat"), std::ios_base::binary);
    const char* cyphert = info.ToEncryptedString();
    if (!outfile.bad())
    {
        outfile << cyphert;
        outfile.close();
    }

    std::ifstream infile(_T("test.dat"), std::ios_base::binary);
    if (!infile.bad())
    {
        stringstream sstr;
        sstr << infile.rdbuf();
        infile.close();

        std::string ss = sstr.str();
        HardWareInfo deserializd;
        deserializd.FromEncryptedString(ss.c_str());
    }
}
```

But it fails with a thrown exception (The second one) stating something about an invalid PKCS block:

```
if (length != s)
    throw InvalidCiphertext("StreamTransformationFilter: ciphertext length is not a multiple of block size");
m_cipher.ProcessData(space, inString, s);
if (m_padding == PKCS_PADDING)
{
    byte pad = space[s-1];
    if (pad < 1 || pad > s || std::find_if(space+s-pad, space+s, std::bind2nd(std::not_equal_to<byte>(), pad)) != space+s)
        throw InvalidCiphertext("StreamTransformationFilter: invalid PKCS #7 block padding found");
    length = s-pad;
}
```

My code calling the decrypt routines is like this:

```
std::string ciphertext = cyphertext
std::string decryptedtext;

CryptoPP::AES::Decryption aesDecryption(key, CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH);
CryptoPP::CBC_Mode_ExternalCipher::Decryption cbcDecryption(aesDecryption, iv);

CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter stfDecryptor(cbcDecryption, new CryptoPP::StringSink(decryptedtext));
stfDecryptor.Put(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(ciphertext.c_str()), ciphertext.size());
stfDecryptor.MessageEnd();
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: When encrypting, you're creating a `char*`, then writing that to the stream, however unless you're performing some conversion (e.g. to Base64), the output may contain `\0`s, which will presumably cause the output to be truncated, preventing subsequent decryption.

Comment: What would you suggest then?

Comment: btw, no matter whether I put in std::ios_base::binary or not, it fails all the same.

Comment: Assuming the problem described in my comment is the cause, you'll need to calculate the number of bytes in `cyphert` and then use `outfile.write(cyphert, lengthInBytes);`. However, since you don't give your encryption code, it's difficult to say whether this will resolve the problem or whether there are other issues that will also need to be corrected.

Comment: Actually I did give my encryption code. Did you read my post above? The code is supplied in the crypto++ library, version 5.6.2. And the code I'm calling  is the last example code snippet above.

Comment: Have you implemented the change indicated in my previous comment? If so, please update your question with the changes, and any new errors. It would be useful for me and anyone else wanting to assist if you were to provide an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/), rather than just snippets.

Comment: sorry, I've been busy. I've a deliverable to get out the door, then I'll get to this. Probably tonight I think.

Answer (score 0):

> deserializd.FromEncryptedString(ss.c_str());

As @Iridium said, this is the problem. It may not be your only issue, though (we would need to see more code).

You need to change that function signature:

```
deserializd.FromEncryptedString(ss.c_str(), ss.length());
```